# Getting dynamically added labels to look like tags

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, code-behind

What I'd like to do is have something similar to what SO does on the main page:

[image]

So, what I did was add this code:

## C# Code-Behind:

```
    protected void LoadInterests()
    {

        //Fill Interests based on table values
        string strSQL2 = "SELECT UM.MatchValue, DD.DDLValue FROM tmpUsermatch UM ";
        strSQL2 = strSQL2 + "INNER JOIN (SELECT StoredValue, DDLValue FROM tmpDropdowns WHERE ddlName = 'ddlInterests') DD ";
        strSQL2 = strSQL2 + "ON UM.MatchValue = DD.StoredValue ";
        strSQL2 = strSQL2 + "WHERE MatchField = 'MatchInterests'  AND UserID = '" + lblUserID.Text + "'";
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(strCon1))
        using (var adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, con))
        {
            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            adapter2.Fill(dt2);
            foreach (DataRow row in dt2.Rows)
            {
                Label dynamicLabel = new Label();
                dynamicLabel.ID = "lbl" + row["DDLValue"].ToString();
                dynamicLabel.Text = row["DDLValue"].ToString();
                dynamicLabel.CssClass = "lbl.interests";
                div1.Controls.Add(dynamicLabel);
            }
        }
    }
```

## asp.net:

```
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="100px" ScrollBars="Vertical" Style="float: left; margin-left: 1px; background-color:#f5f5f5" Width="807px" BorderColor="LightSteelBlue" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px">
            <div id="div1" runat="server" class="clear" style="width:820px; border-width:1px; margin-left:20px"></div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

## CSS:

```
lbl.interests
{
    background-color: #465c71;    
/*    background-color: white;    */
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;  
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The end result is still this:

[image]

when I want it to look like this:

[image]

Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting 'display: inline-block;' ?

Comment: Not a solution, more of a (probably useless) advice: there is a chance of SQL Injection in your code if it goes to production :) (Again, maybe it was written that way only to be posted on SO, but... I got a itch that needs to be scratched :D)

Comment: Also, came to my notice that `<div id='div1'>` should be `<div id='dynamicLabel'>`... typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
dynamicLabel.CssClass = "lbl.interests";
```

to

```
dynamicLabel.CssClass = "lbl interests";
```

AND change CSS selector to

`.lbl.interests`

Remember `.` is used for selecting class name only in CSS, it will not be present in HTML, also if you specify just name in css like `lbl` you are referring to a TAG in HTML which is invalid tag according to HTML and also does match with the code.

My suggestion would be first write plain HTML and CSS and confirm your layout is working as expected, then generate the HTML with C#/ASP.Net

Refer the below link for help on CSS Selectors
[W3Schools - CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: This was a big help!  Needed to do a little more to get where I wanted to go, but this was a huge step.  Thanks!